# How can I update only one key in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have

```
dict = {
 a: { 
  a1: 1 
 }, 
 b : { b1: 2, b2: { b11: 33 } }, 
 c : 12 
}
keys_array = ['b', 'b2', 'b11] 
val = 100
```

function should update only one value in dict and return,
NOT JUST GET IT, I need to update value

`{a: {a1: 1}, b :{b1: 2, b2: {b11:`**100**`}}, c : 12}`

But my function isn`t so smart like i want

```
def update(dict, keys_array, val):
    if len(keys_array) == 1:
        dict[keys_array[0]] = val
    if len(keys_array) == 2:
        dict[keys_array[0]][keys_array[1]] = val
    if len(keys_array) == 3:
        dict[keys_array[0]][keys_array[1]][keys_array[2]] = val
    ...
```

## Solution

````
def update(d, val, *keys):
    if len(keys) >= 1:
        if keys[0] not in d:
            d[keys[0]] = {}
        if len(keys) >= 2:
            d[keys[0]] = update(d[keys[0]], val, *keys[1:])
        elif len(keys) == 1:
            d[keys[0]] = val

    return d```
````

Comment: The duplicate shows you how to loop on the dict keys to get to the element you want.